# How to use BiQuadFilter of NAudio?

Tags: c#, filter, naudio

I use NAudio for recording sound from the microphone and save it in a file. I use for this:

```
    public WaveFileWriter m_WaveFile = null;

    m_WaveFile = new WaveFileWriter(strFile, m_WaveSource.WaveFormat);  


    void DataAvailable(object sender, WaveInEventArgs e)
    {
        if (m_WaveFile != null)
        {
            m_WaveFile.Write(e.Buffer, 0, e.BytesRecorded);
        }
    }
```

Now I would like to apply a highpassfilter and a lowpassfilter to the recorded sound. So far I found that BiQuadFilters would do this for me but so far I don't understand how to use that.

The examples I found look all like this:

```
    var r = BiQuadFilter.LowPassFilter(44100, 1500, 1);
    var reader = new WaveFileReader(File.OpenRead(strFile));
    var filter = new MyWaveProvider(reader, r); // reader is the source for filter
    var waveOut = new WaveOut();
    waveOut.Init(filter); // filter is the source for waveOut
    waveOut.Play();
```

If I understand this correctly then the Filter is applied to the class that is playing the sound. But I don't want to play the sound, I want the high and log pass filter applied to the file and save the result in a file. How can I do that?

edit:
This is MyWaveProvider class:

```
class MyWaveProvider : ISampleProvider
{
    private ISampleProvider sourceProvider;
    private float cutOffFreq;
    private int channels;
    private BiQuadFilter[] filters;

    public MyWaveProvider (ISampleProvider sourceProvider, int cutOffFreq)
    {
        this.sourceProvider = sourceProvider;
        this.cutOffFreq = cutOffFreq;

        channels = sourceProvider.WaveFormat.Channels;
        filters = new BiQuadFilter[channels];
        CreateFilters();
    }

    private void CreateFilters()
    {
        for (int n = 0; n < channels; n++)
            if (filters[n] == null)
                filters[n] = BiQuadFilter.LowPassFilter(44100, cutOffFreq, 1);
            else
                filters[n].SetLowPassFilter(44100, cutOffFreq, 1);
    }

    public WaveFormat WaveFormat { get { return sourceProvider.WaveFormat; } }

    public int Read(float[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        int samplesRead = sourceProvider.Read(buffer, offset, count);

        for (int i = 0; i < samplesRead; i++)
            buffer[offset + i] = filters[(i % channels)].Transform(buffer[offset + i]);

        return samplesRead;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The following code should satisfy what you are trying to do:

```
using (var reader = new WaveFileReader(File.OpenRead(strFile)))
{
    var r = BiQuadFilter.LowPassFilter(44100, 1500, 1);

    // reader is the source for filter
    using (var filter =  new MyWaveProvider(reader, r))
    {
        WaveFileWriter.CreateWaveFile("filteroutput.wav", filter);
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your hint but MyWaveProvider is from ISampleProvider which isn't an valid argument for CreateWaveFile

Comment: Sorry -- I did not have an environment available to try it with, but I thought I had checked at least that there was an overload for  `ISampleProvider` -- I guess not.  Thanks.

Comment: @computermaus -- I just re-checked the source code.  There is a method called `CreateWaveFile16()` that accepts an `ISampleProvider`.  Can you try `WaveFileWriter.CreateWaveFile16( "output.wav", filter);`

Comment: Yes, if you have a `ISampleProvider`, use `CreateWaveFile16` or use `ToWaveProvider` extension if you actually want a 32 bit IEEE float WAV file

Answer (score 0):

There's an example of using the `BiQuadFilter` to make a multi-band equalizer in the NAudio WPF demo code. You can see the `Equalizer` code [here](https://github.com/naudio/NAudio/blob/master/NAudio.Extras/Equalizer.cs)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I looked at this example and so far I managed to create the a class from ISampleProvider and it seems to work. But How can I save the result after applying the filter? Davids example here with CreateWaveFile isn't working because this doesn't accept a ISampleProvider as an argument