# Can I apply filter(low/high pass) to WaveIn data (Naudio)

Tags: audio, filter, naudio

I use Naudio to playback real time audio data. At the same time ı want to filter(low/high pass) this stream. How can that be done?

Here is the code I have so far:

```
public WaveIn InputWave { get; set; }

public void InputWaveConstructor() 
        {
            data.InputWave = new NAudio.Wave.WaveIn()
            {
                DeviceNumber = data.DeviceNumberIn,
                WaveFormat = new NAudio.Wave.WaveFormat(_sampleRate, _bitDepth, NAudio.Wave.WaveIn.GetCapabilities(data.DeviceNumberIn).Channels),
                BufferMilliseconds = _bufferMilliseconds
            };

            data.WaveIn = new NAudio.Wave.WaveInProvider(data.InputWave);

            data.InputMonoWave = new StereoToMonoSampleProvider(data.WaveIn.ToSampleProvider());
        }
```

```
public void Playback(float leftVolume, float rightVolume) 
        {

            data.InputWave.StartRecording();

            data.InputMonoWave.LeftVolume = leftVolume;
            data.InputMonoWave.RightVolume = rightVolume;

            data.OutputWave = new NAudio.Wave.WaveOut()
            {
                DeviceNumber = data.DeviceNumberOut
            };

            data.OutputWave.Init(data.InputMonoWave);
            data.OutputWave.Play();
        }
```

I have tried `biquadFilter`, but I couldn't find where / how to use it.

Comment: Please remove the excessive leading indentation from your code block (see [What should I keep out of my posts and titles?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/131009/997587)). Can you please also add syntax highlighting to your code blocks? You can see [/editing-help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for how to do so.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47212311/how-to-use-biquadfilter-of-naudio