# How to apply a Low pass filter to my .WAV audio file using NAudio

Tags: c#, naudio

I am trying to get an audio sample, extract its volume, normalize another file based on the first one's volume, then try to eliminate as much static noise with a low pass filter as possible and then finally convert it to MP3 format.

I know the NAudio library has an integrated class called "BiQuadFilter" to be able to use a Low Pass filter with lets say 1500 cut off frequency.

My problem here is that I dont know how to use this class, I know that after creating the "LowPassFilter" it has a method called "transform" that receives a float and returns a float but Im not sure if I should be using the floats I'm reading from the file.

Help would be appreciated

This is the method to try and normalize the audio

```
void audioNormalizer(string validFile, string inPath, string outPath)
{
    float max = 0;

    using (var reader = new AudioFileReader(validFile))
    {
        // find the max peak
        float[] buffer = new float[reader.WaveFormat.SampleRate];
        int read;
        int cont = 0;
        do
        {
            read = reader.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            for (int n = 0; n < read; n++)
            {
                var abs = Math.Abs(buffer[n]);
                if (abs > max) max = abs;
            }
            cont++;
        } while (read > 0);
        Console.WriteLine($"Max sample value: {max}");

        if (max == 0 || max > 1.0f)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("File cannot be normalized");
        using (var reader2 = new AudioFileReader(inPath))
        {
            reader2.Position = 0;
            reader2.Volume = 1.0f / max;
            string wavOutPath = outPath.Substring(0, outPath.IndexOf(".")) + ".wav";

            //********** HERE IS WERE I WOULD APPLY A LOW PASS FILTER 
            var filter = BiQuadFilter.LowPassFilter(44100, 1500, 1);
            //********** DO SOMETHING WITH THIS FILTER TO GET THE FLOAT VALUES TRANSFORMED 

            WaveFileWriter.CreateWaveFile(wavOutPath, reader2);
            File.WriteAllBytes(outPath, ConvertToMp3(wavOutPath));
            if (File.Exists(wavOutPath))
            {
                File.Delete(wavOutPath);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the ConvertToMp3 method

```
byte[] ConvertToMp3(string path)
{

    byte[] file = File.ReadAllBytes(path);
    var target = new WaveFormat(44100, 16, 1);
    using (var outPutStream = new MemoryStream())
    using (var waveStream = new WaveFileReader(new MemoryStream(file)))
    using (var conversionStream = new WaveFormatConversionStream(target, waveStream))
    using (var writer = new LameMP3FileWriter(outPutStream, conversionStream.WaveFormat, 32, null))
    {
        conversionStream.CopyTo(writer);
        return outPutStream.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47212311/how-to-use-biquadfilter-of-naudio

Comment: HI I have already seen that post and tried what they do @HansPassant but it doesnt work, the static noise doesnt get reduced, it only lowers the volume output.